# Ставится ли запятая перед "или"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, или

***Кони или пони,похожие на сказочных существ.***

Суть вопроса:

*Если предложение выглядит двояко:*

Кони или **пони,которые похожи на сказочных существ.**(только пони похожи на сказочных существ)

**Кони или пони**,которые похожи на сказочных существ.(кони и пони похожи на сказочных существ)

*- То зависит ли от смысла постановка запятой перед "или"?
Если запятая не ставится,то как определить правильный смысл предложения?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ПОНИ,** м. Лошадь мелкой и низкорослой породы, выведенная на Британских островах. Низкорослые, выносливые, гривастые п. Кататься на п.

Прежде всего, для ответа **нужен полный текст** предложения (это же скорее словосочетание), а так можно только догадываться, о чём речь.

Сравнить: пони, или маленькие кони ― **пояснительный союз ИЛИ**, наоборот же  не получается.

Кони или пони ― **разделительный союз ИЛИ** (неясно, кто это: кони или пони).

Поэтому: **Кони или пони, похожие на сказочных существ.** Определение общее: похоже и те и другие (правда, мы еще не разобрались, кто перед нами).

Answer (score 1):

> ***Кони или пони, похожие на сказочных существ...***
>
> ...предложение выглядит двояко.

Если смущает двоякость, попробуйте рассмотреть такой вариант:

***Похожие на сказочных существ то ли кони, то ли пони...***